# LinkedListStack System.out.println

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

Im working on a `LinkedListStack` and have to print out for example "size".
here is my `LinkedListStack`:

```
public class LinkedListStack {

    private class Element {
        public Object value;
        public Element next;
    }

    private Element top;
    private int size=0;

    public void push(Object o) {
        Element e=new Element();
        e.value=o;
        e.next=top;
        top=e;
        size++;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        if (top!=null) {
            Object v=top.value;
            top=top.next;
            size--;
            return v;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return top==null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public Object get(int n) {
        Element current=top;
        int i=0;
        while (i<n && current!=null) {
            current=current.next;
            i++;
        }
        if (current==null)
            return null;
        else
            return current.value;
    }

}
```

I know I have to use

```
System.out.println ("...");
```

and that i need a new class, let's call it `Stacki`. Is must contain a `main` method where i can use the methods and print them out. So that would be:

```
public class Stacki {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

how do I put

```
public void size() {
    System.out.println ("size is"+size());
}
```

in that class? Because i cannot use the block as such, an error occurs.

Thank you :)

Comment: You need to define an `object` of **LinkedListStack** first

Answer (score 3):

You instantiate your other class within Stacki, like:

```
public class Stacki {

 public static void main(String[]) {
   LinkedListStack stack = new LinkedListStack();
   System.out.println("size is: " + stack.size());
```

... then you probably add some elements, remove some, and whenever you want to:

```
   System.out.println("size is: " + stack.size());
```

And hint: Stacki is a rather nothing-saying name. Better call that class LinkedListStackTester or something alike. Names always say what the thing they denote is about!

And finally: this is really **basic** stuff. It doesn't make much sense to create your own stack class, when you have no idea how to put that to use. In that sense: you probably want to spend some hours [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) and work yourself through those tutorials!